# How to merge two objects using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

[image]

Consider two JSON objects, I want to merge these two objects and delete duplicated properties

Comment: can you post the code snippet instead of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**angular.forEach()** will solve you problem

```
var obj1 = {a:"hello",b:"user1",c:"user2"},obj2={a:"hello",b:"user1"};

angular.forEach(obj1,function(value,key){
 angular.forEach(obj2,function(value2,key2){
   if(key2 === key){
    delete obj[key];
   }
 })
});
```

Comment: There's no need to loop through both objects. You can use the `hasOwnProperty` method to check if `obj2` contains the property from `obj1`

Answer (score 2):

The **Angular way** to do this is by using [Angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
var merged_object = angular.extend({}, $scope.test1, $scope.test2)
console.log(merged_object)
```